unsealing of vault failing with 400 error
InitStatus() api is returning vault status as initialized.
When trying to unseal, getting API error.
Unable to unseal vault server, Error making API request.
URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:5817/v1/sys/unseal
Code: 400. Errors:

Vault is not initialized

Can someone suggest what is going wrong?
Was trying to unseal vault.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
